# Show iframe code rather than website

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

```
  <pre><code><iframe width="100%" height="400" src="http://google.com"   frameborder="0"></iframe></code></pre>
```

I don't want to show the iframe content, just the code. Above is what I have tried..

SOLUTION:

I used  to wrap my iframe code

Comment: that isn't the same

Answer (score -1):

If you prefix the URL with "view-source:" the browser shows the source code instead of the webpage.